# Polylang vs мультисайт

Tags: wordpress, мультиязычность

*Всем, здравствуйте! Я не против некоторых плагинов, но не часто и за. Может, кто даст совет или уже был опыт с Polylang и мультисайтом... Что в этом плане, думаете, лучше?*

*Вопрос в том, что можно создать на мультисайте, разные языки сайтов, но планируется их от 5 до 7 языков. И что в этом плане лучше? Так как WordPress версии обновляются со временем (что придётся обновлять все версии языков), мультисайт создаёт много базы данных (то есть копии с префиксом wp1, wp2 и т.д.).*

*То есть в плане Seo они оба подходят, так как создаются дополнительные страницы, записи, каталоги...*

***Но, что, вы бы посоветовали?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посоветовал бы не заниматься ерундой и использовать плагины мультиязычности - Polylang или WPML. Мультисайт не для этого создан.

Вы просто не представляете себе какой объём работы по синхронизации и переводу постов, страниц, кастомных постов, таксономий, произвольных полей и т.д. вам придётся выполнить на мультисайте.

Кто будет заниматься переводом на все эти 5-7 языков? Каким образом? Вручную править все материалы? Сайты с таким набором языков полагаются на агентства переводов, которым плагин мультиязычности (WPML или Polylang) отсылает тексты на основном языке, извлечённые из статьи и автоматически получает назад переводы. Затем плагин мультиязычности корректно преобразует переведённые строки в страницы на других языках.

Comment: Плюсую. Откуда только эта мода взялась - мультисайта для мультиязчности. Не иначе плагинофоия. Но стоит в последнем абзаце заменить "WPML" на "и WPML и Polilang". Они оба это всё могут. И не только с англ текстами.

Comment: Ни один плагин, кроме WPML не работает с живыми людьми - переводческими бюро.

Comment: Полиленг работает

Comment: @SeVlad да ладно, где это написано, покажи

Comment: @SeVlad вот как умеет WPML, почитай про translation services https://wpml.org/documentation/translating-your-contents/professional-translation-via-wpml/ Выбираешь контент, оттуда WPML вытаскивает строки, отправляет их в бюро переводов, а когда человек в бюро закончил перевод, он шлёт это назад. И на сайте надо только посмотреть и принять этот перевод.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/BbQOybE.jpeg - это прямо в бесплатной версии. И надеюсь,  что тебя надеюсь не смущает что полиланг это делает через доп [плагин](https://wordpress.org/plugins/lingotek-translation/)?

Comment: @SeVlad я узнал для себя что-то новое, спасибо. Хорошо, что есть Lingotek.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129983/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-sevlad).